# Format a decimal in background code java

Tags: java, floating-point

I have a program which asks for the price of a Shirt in a method called `getCost()`. When I run my main class, the decimal prints out like $4.5, and doesn't go to 2 decimal places.

In my main class, I created a `DecimalFormat` object to try and take care of this issue, but it doesn't help. I feel like I either instantiated it wrong, or I am using it wrong. If decimal format does not work, how can I use `printf` or any other form to fix this issue?

Here is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (in);
  Object[] Shirts = new Object [6];

  Shirt one = new Shirt(10, false, "green" , "stripes", 14.99);
  Shirts[0] = one;
  Shirt two = new Shirt(9, true, "red", "stripes", 22.90);
  Shirts[1] = two;

  int sz = 0;
  boolean slvs = false;
  String clr = " ";
  String ptrn = " ";
  double cst = 0.0;

  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

  //SHIRT 3
  out.println("What is your shirt size::");
  sz = sc.nextInt();
  out.println();

  out.println("How much does your shirt cost::");
  cst = sc.nextDouble();
  //decimal format here
  formatter.format(cst);
  out.println();

  out.println("Your shirt has sleeves. True or False?");
  slvs = sc.nextBoolean();
  out.println();
  sc.nextLine();

  out.println("What is the color of your shirt::");
  clr = sc.nextLine();
  out.println();

  out.println("What pattern does your shirt have::");
  ptrn = sc.nextLine();

  Shirt three = new Shirt(sz,slvs,clr,ptrn,cst);
  sc.nextLine();

  Arrays.sort(Shirts);

  for(int x = 0; x < Shirts.length - 1; x++)
  {
    out.println(Shirts[x].toString());
  }
```

Here is the `toString()` in my `Shirt` class:

```
 public String toString()
 {
   String str= "Size: " + getSize() + ", It has sleeves: " + getSleeves() + ", Color: "+ getColor() + ", Pattern: " + getPtrn() + ", Cost: $" + getCost();
   return str;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your `Shirt#toString()` method? The purpose of the formatter is to format the `String` when you _display_ it, not when you _save_ it.

Comment: @Narmer i added my toString()

Comment: Look at using `printf` with `%.2f`

Comment: @Ascalonian where would I add that?

Comment: In your `toString()`. Do a Google search for printf examples and a lot will come up. For example: [A printf format reference cheat sheet](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet)

Comment: also, as a side note about coding conventions, don't start the name of your variables with a capital letter (e.g. `Shirts`). Instead it should be `shirts` or maybe `shirtArray`. Items that start with a capital letter should be Class names only (or constants, technically haha)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the formatter is to format the `String` when you *display* it, not when you *"save"* it.
Remove all your `formatter.format(whatever)`, you don't need to format the double when putting it into the `shirt` (also, you are not doing anything with that line of code).

You need to format when you *display* the `double`, in your `toString()` method:

```
public String toString()
 {
  String str= "Size: " + getSize() + 
              ", It has sleeves: " + getSleeves() + 
              ", Color: "+ getColor() + 
              ", Pattern: " + getPtrn() + 
              ", Cost: $" + formatter.format(getCost()); //Format here
  return str;
 }
```

Obviously your `DecimalFormat` must be inside the `Shirt` class.

Also your pattern isn't correct if you want to *always* display at least 2 digits. It should be:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

[The 0 character is used instead of the pound sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html). So `4,3` becomes `4,30`.

Comment: I added what you said, however, if I have a cost of $6.70 or any price ending in 0, the 0 gets left off. When I run my main class, it still displays the cost as $6.7. But when I have a price of $5.75 or anything other number besides 0, it displays fine. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Ohh, I just saw your last line. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to reside within the `toString()` method:

```
 public String toString()
 {
      String str= "Size: " + getSize() + ", It has sleeves: " + getSleeves() + ", Color: "+ getColor() + ", Pattern: " + getPtrn() + ", Cost: $" + getCost();
  return str;
 }
```

Since no formatting seems to be done on whatever it is that `getCost()` yields.

To fix this, try this:

```
 public String toString()
 {         
     String str= "Size: " + getSize() + ", It has sleeves: " + getSleeves() + ", Color: "+ getColor() + ", Pattern: " + getPtrn() + ", Cost: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(getCost());
     return str;
 }
```